# Unit tests for Angular Kendo Grid

Tags: angular, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

Downloaded a sample of Kendo UI Grid for Angular. Need to know how to write unit test cases for the grid to verify features and functionalities such as sorting, filtering, values in current page, etc.

Have not found any documentation or samples related to writing unit test cases for Angular Kendo UI components.

This link provides unit tests for sorting and Telerik Grid, but for Win Forms.
https://www.telerik.com/forums/unit-test-for-sorting-filtering---radgridview

Kindly suggest some examples.

Comment: You should not have to write tests for a UI library. It is your responsibility to write tests for your app's components.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I'm starting to look into unit testing a component that makes use of kendo controls, e.g. the grid